# Convertir un array en string

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo este array

```
[12, 13, 22]
```

pero necesito quitar los corchetes y los espacios. Debería imprimirme lo siguiente:

```
12,13,14
```

Comment: ¿Pero es un array o es una cadena?

Comment: perdon es una cadena resultante

Comment: ¿Una cadena que sacas de un array?

Comment: Aqui te dejo el ejemplo [link](https://jsbin.com/fuduxedemo/edit?js,console)

Comment: @RafaelPereira por favor, no lo agregues en otro sitio. Podés [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código acá mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empleando el método [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toString) podría lograr este resultado, *(respuesta adaptada a su código del comentario).*

```js
var array1= [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900];
var array2=[1,2,5];
var posit = array2.map(function(el){
 return array1[el];
});


console.log(posit.toString()); // uso del método
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicada la pregunta, puedes hacerlo con [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), como ya ha dicho @DevJoel.

Y, tratándose de un `array` creo que es mejor usar `join` que `toString`.

El método [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) une todos los elementos de un arreglo en una cadena. El separador por defecto es la coma `,`, y te ofrece la posibilidad de usar otro separador si fuera necesario. Además, si un elemento es `undefined` o `null` es convertido a una cadena vacía.

Para otros separadores, ver ejemplos en el enlace de la documentación.

Aquí muestro una forma simplificada:

```js
var act = [10002197,10001755,10001087,10001879,3508477478,10001881];
var posiciones = [0,2,3] // el debera imprimir (10002197,10001087,10001879)

var arrResultado = posiciones.map(i => act[i]);
document.write(arrResultado.join());
```

Comment: @Mariano he vuelto a `join`. Me vino la duda de cuál era mejor, y según he leído, cuando se trata de arrays es mejor usar `join`. Sería interesante tener algo documentado al respecto.

Comment: seria interesante , aunque a primera valoración no se nota cuál es mejor que otro . claro está que con `join` le da la posibilidad de elegir un separador.

Comment: @A.Cedano `toString()` llama a `join()` en la mayoría de los navegadores. Aunque en algunos `join()` es más rápido, y en otros `toString()` es más rápido, las diferencias no son significativas. No obstante, creo que es mejor, desde el punto de vista conceptual, explicar a alguien que está iniciando en JavaScript que `join()` es la forma de unir a un array.

Comment: @Dev.Joel, yo me refería al rendimiento, sobre todo en casos en los que éste pueda ser importante, como por ejemplo manejando datos de gran volumen o algo así.

Comment: Si `toString()` llama a `join()`, entonces es más conveniente llamar directo a la función `join()`

Comment: @Mariano me parece interesante el manejo que hace `join` de los `undefine` y de los valores nulos. Y, como dice Eduardo, es mejor llamar que mandar a llamar.

Answer (score 1):

la mejor opción y más rápida es

```
array = [1,2,3,5]
console.log(array.join())
```

te devolverá los elementos del array en un string separados por una coma , si quieres una separación distinta especificalo dentro del join " `join(";")` "