# toString vs join vs String para convertir un array a cadena en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, string, rendimiento, buenas-prácticas

Si quiero convertir un array en cadena, puedo hacerlo con `toString`, con `join` o con `String`.

En este código, el resultado es el mismo:

```js
var arrPrueba=[4,22,9,50];

var strJoin=arrPrueba.join();
console.log(strJoin);

var strToString=arrPrueba.toString();
console.log(strToString);

var strString=String(arrPrueba);
console.log(strString);
```

Pero, ¿qué método conviene usar tratándose de un array y por qué? ¿Podría haber diferencias importantes por ejemplo a nivel de rendimiento u otras?

Comment: Cambiaría [tag:buenas-practicas] por [tag:performance]

Comment: [Aquí puedes ver](https://jsperf.com/array-tostring-vs-array-join) lo comentado por Mariano

Comment: Gracias @Marcos.  ¿La nota que dice *higher is better* significa que es mejor el más largo? Si pensamos en la duración, los datos se podrían interpretar al revés, pero parece que calcula la cantidad de operaciones que puede hacer, no la duración.

Comment: @A.Cedano, significa que se realizan mas "_Operaciones por segundo_", es decir, que en igual cantidad de tiempo se pudieron realizar mas operaciones. Es por eso que el que de "_Mas alto es mejor_"

Comment: @A.Cedano, en mi opinión, creo que se debería considerar una buena práctica usar `join(',')`, para evitar posible mutaciones en el resultado (_poco probable pero... nunca se sabe_).

Comment: Pienso que esta pregunta debería estar con el tag c/c++ que es con lo que está escrito javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Resumen.** `join()` y `toString()` tienen diferencias mínimas (apenas o no significativas), que varían según navegador y versión. Si se trata de un código *extremadamente* intensivo, concatenar manualmente tiene un mejor rendimiento en Chrome con arrays de pocos elementos, pero la operación en sí no consume tanto tiempo como para influir en la gran mayoría de los escenarios *normales*. Para arrays de muchos elementos, los 3 métodos se comportan por igual. En pos de la legibilidad del código, yo usaría `array.join(',')`.

---

Primero las diferencias que no vamos a considerar:

- [`Array.prototype.join([separador = ","])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join) acepta un separador diferente a la coma, pero para la comparación nos enfocamos exclusivamente en un resultado unido por comas.
- [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/toString) debería llamar a `Array.join()`, tal cual [está definido en ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring), haciendo que sea levemente menos eficiente (por la llamada extra). Sin embargo, sabemos que los navegadores no siempre respetan el estándar al pie de la letra, o podrían no realizar esa llamada a `join` sino al mismo código que se ejecuta en ese método, por lo que no lo vamos a asumir.
- `join()` mostraba un comportamiento completamente diferente en navegadores que no seguían el estándar de ECMAScript (incluso podía ser más eficiente), pero era en versiones ya obsoletas. Es arcaico, y no es relevante.
- Todos los resultados son para JavaScript ejecutado en navegadores. Node.js puede dar resultados muy diferentes, no incluidos en esta respuesta.

---

## Eficiencia

#### ¿`toString()` llama a `join()`?

Así está definido en [el estándar](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring), veamos el código fuente:

- **Chrome** ([fuente](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/4.2-lkgr/src/array.js#350))

  ```
  function ArrayToString() {
      var array;
      var func;
      if (IS_ARRAY(this)) {
          func = this.join;
          if (func === ArrayJoin) {
              return Join(this, this.length, ',', ConvertToString);
          }
          array = this;
      } else {
          array = ToObject(this);
          func = array.join;
      }
      if (!IS_SPEC_FUNCTION(func)) {
          return %_CallFunction(array, DefaultObjectToString);
      }
      return %_CallFunction(array, func);
  }
  ```

  En donde, si es un array, devuelve `Join(this, this.length, ',', ConvertToString);`.

  Y aquí la diferencia: en `ArrayJoin` ([fuente](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/4.2-lkgr/src/array.js#379)) se realiza una comprobación extra.

  ```
  function ArrayJoin(separator) {
      CHECK_OBJECT_COERCIBLE(this, "Array.prototype.join");
      var array = TO_OBJECT_INLINE(this);
      var length = TO_UINT32(array.length);
      if (IS_UNDEFINED(separator)) {
          separator = ',';
      } else if (!IS_STRING(separator)) {
          separator = NonStringToString(separator);
      }
      var result = %_FastOneByteArrayJoin(array, separator);
      if (!IS_UNDEFINED(result)) return result;
      // Fast case for one-element arrays.
      if (length === 1) {
          var e = array[0];
          if (IS_STRING(e)) return e;
          if (IS_NULL_OR_UNDEFINED(e)) return '';
          return NonStringToString(e);
      }
      return Join(array, length, separator, ConvertToString);
  }
  ```

  Primero, intenta llamar a `%_FastOneByteArrayJoin`, que es una optimización para casos de arrays con elementos de 1 byte. Luego, verifica si el array tiene un único elemento para devolverlo directamente. Recién si fallan estos dos (algún elemento tiene más de 1 byte y el array tiene más de 1 elemento), ahí se llama a `Join(array, length, separator, ConvertToString);`.

  Entonces, esperaríamos que en Chrome `join()` sea más rápido con arrays de elementos de 1 byte o con 1 único elemento, y levemente menos eficiente con los demás.

- **FireFox** ([fuente](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/rev/95352ef5e38ee720c451c92177383833b5444665/js/src/builtin/Array.js#898)):

  ```
  // ES2015 22.1.3.27 Array.prototype.toString.
  function ArrayToString() {
      // Steps 1-2.
      var array = ToObject(this);

      // Steps 3-4.
      var func = array.join;

      // Steps 5-6.
      if (!IsCallable(func))
          return callFunction(std_Object_toString, array);
      return callContentFunction(func, array);
  }
  ```

  De nuevo, `callContentFunction(array.join, array);`.

  Pero en este caso, está llamando [directamente](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/rev/95352ef5e38ee720c451c92177383833b5444665/js/src/jit/VMFunctions.cpp#444) a la definición para `js::array_join` ([fuente](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-beta/rev/95352ef5e38ee720c451c92177383833b5444665/js/src/jsarray.cpp#1333)).

  ```
  // ES2017 draft rev 1b0184bc17fc09a8ddcf4aeec9b6d9fcac4eafce
  // 22.1.3.13 Array.prototype.join ( separator )
  bool
  js::array_join(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, Value* vp)
  {
      if (!CheckRecursionLimit(cx))
          return false;

      AutoGeckoProfilerEntry pseudoFrame(cx, "Array.prototype.join");
      CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);

      // Step 1.
      RootedObject obj(cx, ToObject(cx, args.thisv()));
      if (!obj)
          return false;

      AutoCycleDetector detector(cx, obj);
      if (!detector.init())
          return false;

      if (detector.foundCycle()) {
          args.rval().setString(cx->names().empty);
          return true;
      }

      // Step 2.
      uint64_t length;
      if (!GetLengthProperty(cx, obj, &length))
          return false;

      // Steps 3-4.
      RootedLinearString sepstr(cx);
      if (args.hasDefined(0)) {
          JSString *s = ToString<CanGC>(cx, args[0]);
          if (!s)
              return false;
          sepstr = s->ensureLinear(cx);
          if (!sepstr)
              return false;
      } else {
          sepstr = cx->names().comma;
      }

      // Steps 5-8 (When the length is zero, directly return the empty string).
      if (length == 0) {
          args.rval().setString(cx->emptyString());
          return true;
      }

      // An optimized version of a special case of steps 5-8: when length==1 and
      // the 0th element is a string, ToString() of that element is a no-op and
      // so it can be immediately returned as the result.
      if (length == 1 && obj->isNative()) {
          NativeObject* nobj = &obj->as<NativeObject>();
          if (nobj->getDenseInitializedLength() == 1) {
              Value elem0 = nobj->getDenseElement(0);
              if (elem0.isString()) {
                  args.rval().set(elem0);
                  return true;
              }
          }
      }

      // Step 5.
      StringBuffer sb(cx);
      if (sepstr->hasTwoByteChars() && !sb.ensureTwoByteChars())
          return false;

      // The separator will be added |length - 1| times, reserve space for that
      // so that we don't have to unnecessarily grow the buffer.
      size_t seplen = sepstr->length();
      if (seplen > 0) {
          if (length > UINT32_MAX) {
              ReportAllocationOverflow(cx);
              return false;
          }
          CheckedInt<uint32_t> res = CheckedInt<uint32_t>(seplen) * (uint32_t(length) - 1);
          if (!res.isValid()) {
              ReportAllocationOverflow(cx);
              return false;
          }

          if (!sb.reserve(res.value()))
              return false;
      }

      // Various optimized versions of steps 6-7.
      if (seplen == 0) {
          EmptySeparatorOp op;
          if (!ArrayJoinKernel(cx, op, obj, length, sb))
              return false;
      } else if (seplen == 1) {
          char16_t c = sepstr->latin1OrTwoByteChar(0);
          if (c <= JSString::MAX_LATIN1_CHAR) {
              CharSeparatorOp<Latin1Char> op(c);
              if (!ArrayJoinKernel(cx, op, obj, length, sb))
                  return false;
          } else {
              CharSeparatorOp<char16_t> op(c);
              if (!ArrayJoinKernel(cx, op, obj, length, sb))
                  return false;
          }
      } else {
          StringSeparatorOp op(sepstr);
          if (!ArrayJoinKernel(cx, op, obj, length, sb))
              return false;
      }

      // Step 8.
      JSString* str = sb.finishString();
      if (!str)
          return false;

      args.rval().setString(str);
      return true;
  }
  ```

  Entonces, en Firefox esperaríamos que `join(',')` sea levemente más eficiente.

- **IE/Edge**

  No encontré la fuente, y en Microsoft Docs [está definido](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/scripting/javascript/reference/tostring-method-array) como:

  > Los elementos de un `Array` se convierten en cadenas. Las cadenas resultantes se concatenan y separadas por comas.

  Por lo que podríamos esperar una diferencia acá.

#### Benchmark para arrays de pocos elementos

Vayamos al grano, hasta ahora fueron puras especulaciones. Empecemos analizando el comportamiento de cada método en arrays de pocos elementos, dentro del rando de las decenas, que es el caso de uso habitual. Armé el benchmark en JSPerf para arrays de 16 elementos:

#### https://jsperf.com/array-join-vs-tostring-vs-string

Estos resultados van a depender siempre de navegador, versión, sistema operativo, hardware y carga actual del equipo. Van a variar, pero a modo general nos sirve para comparar.

- [image] **Chrome 63** (Win 10)

  [image: Chrome 63]
  <sup>**más es mejor**</sup>

  - `toString()` es levemente más rápido, como esperábamos (el benchmark es con un ejemplo que no cae dentro de las optimizaciones de `ArrayJoin`).

    > Chrome para Windows o Android es el único donde es así (en todo el resto veremos que es al revés).

    Sin embargo, la diferencia es de solamente un ~1%. Lo que quiere decir que, para un array de 16 strings, `toString()` tarda ~1µs, y `join()` apenas tarda ~0.01µs más. A veces se solapa dentro del margen de error, y es **completamente despreciable** para la mayoría de los casos.
  - `String()` sí tiene una diferencia notoria. Idealmente, si nos interesa la eficiencia no conviene dejar que el intérprete haga la conversión de tipos automáticamente.
  - Dato de color: `join(',')` suele ser más rápido que `join()`, aunque la diferencia no es significativa.
  - No hubo diferencias importantes entre un array de strings y uno de números para `join()` ni para `toString()`.
  - Chrome para Android muestra resultados similares, aunque con diferencias menores entre cada método y, por las características de Android, menos estables y en algunas pruebas puntuales hasta puede invertirse la relación entre `join()` y `toString()`.
  - Las versiones de Chrome de hace algunos años mostraban este mismo comportamiento (por ejemplo, [Chrome 51 (2016)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sn3u.png)), pero `join()` sacaba una diferencia significativa en versiones mucho más viejas (por ejemplo, [Chrome 38 (2014)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RtCL.png)).

- [image] **FireFox 53**

  [image: FireFox 53]

  - Como esperábamos, `join(',')` es levemente más eficiente. Pero **la diferencia no es significativa** y entra dentro del margen de error.
  - Un array de enteros es algo más lento (~25%) que un array de strings. Aparentemente hay una demora significativa en la conversión de tipos.
  - El resto de las conclusiones concuerdan con las de Chrome.

- [image] **IE 11**

  [image: IE 11]

  - IE sí **presenta diferencias significativas** entre los métodos. `join()` es el más rápido.
  - Un array de strings se convierte más de 2 veces más rápido que un array de enteros.

- [image] **Edge 16**

  [image: Edge 16]

  - Resultados análogos a IE.

- [image] **Chrome 63 (MacOS X)**

  [image: Chrome 63 (MacOS X)]

  - En Chrome para Mac, `join()` parece llevar una leve ventaja (no significativa).

- [image] **Safari 11 (MacOS X)**

  [image: Safari 11 - MacOS X]

  - Resultados análogos a IE, con una diferencia más acentuada a favor de `join()`.
  - Y mismos resultados en [iPhone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObZI3.png).

> Nota:
>   Es de esperarse que en donde las diferencias no son significativas se observen comportamientos diferentes, dependiendo de cada sistema, e incluso puedan llegar a ser inversos a los resultados presentados acá. Estos resultados sirven como patrón a grandes rasgos de las diferencias de rendimiento, pero **no quiere decir que estas relaciones se vayan a mantener siempre igual**.

#### ¿Existe un método más rápido para pocos elementos?

Sigamos fanatizados con la eficiencia. ¿Hay algo mejor que los métodos nativos?

**El origen del caos: teoría de strings.** Gran parte de los lenguajes modernos emplean el "paradigma del objeto inmutable", que sirve para resolver varios problemas (en concurremcia, alocación en caché, conservación de memoria, entre otros). Si un objeto es inmutable, su valor no puede cambiar. Y un objeto inmutable puede ser representado por referencia (punteros), ya que pasar la referencia es análogo a pasar el valor, por lo que permite el gran beneficio de poder replicar las referencias sin la necesidad de replicar los valores (algo que sería muchísimo más costoso).

¿Y para cambiarle el valor? Los Strings son inmutables en JavaScript. Todas las operaciones que modifiquen un String, en realidad están devolviendo un objeto nuevo con el resultado de la operación, dejando al objeto original inmutado. Por ejemplo,

```
textoA.concat( textoB )
```

simplemente devuelve una nueva cadena (un nuevo objeto). El tema es que las operaciones sobre strings conllevan un costo extra: el costo de copiar y reemplazar. Tradicionalmente la concatenación de strings fue uno de los aspectos más pobres de JavaScript por este motivo, y hace algunos años las operaciones con Arrays eran muchísimo más eficientes que las operaciones con Strings. Muchos desarrolladores se percataban de esto y volcaban el código a Arrays o clases del estilo de un StringBuilder.

[image: Concatenación de srings vs. Array()]

Por ejemplo, si queríamos buscar y reemplazar una subcadena, era mucho menos costoso la técnica de hacer un split y join (pasar un Array como referencia, agregándole cada parte del texto entre subcadenas, y luego unirlos agregando el texto de reemplazo), retrasando así el costo de la mutación de strings hasta que sea absolutamente necesario.

**Optimización de strings.** Evolucionó JavaScript en los últimos 20 años, y este caso ya no existe. Se incluyó un gran conjunto de optimizaciones sobre las operaciones con Strings. FireFox fue el primero en optimizar la concatenación allá por su primera versión. Hoy en día, todos los navegadores modernos presentan muchísimas optimizaciones, haciendo que la concatenación no sea tan costosa como lo era antes. No obstante, para algunos escenarios puntuales estas 2 fuerzas siguen compitiendo hoy en día, mostrando resultados diferentes según el caso.

**`Array.join(',')` versus Concatenación de Strings para pocos elementos.** Teniendo todas las optimizaciones actuales en la concatenación de Strings, ¿qué es más eficiente? ¿Concatenar los elementos manualmente o usar la función nativa?

Tomando este código para concatenar manualmente a `arr`:

```
resultado = '';
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i<len; i++){
    resultado += (i===0?'':',') + arr[i];
}
```

usamos el benchmark anterior para comparar.

- [image] **Chrome 63** (Win 10)

  [image: Chrome 63]

  - En Chrome, tenemos claramente un ganador. Concatenar manualmente cada elemento con `+=` demuestra ser significativamente más eficiente con arrays de pocos elementos.

  > De nuevo, Chrome es el único con este comportamiento. Todos los demás navegadores muestran que `join(',')` es más eficiente.

- [image] **FireFox 57**

  [image: FireFox 57]

  - La concatenación con `+=` muestra un rendimiento excesivamente bajo.
  - Pero en FireFox tenemos un nuevo ganador. [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) tiene una mejor performance que el resto. Este es el código empleado:

    ```
    resultado = arr.reduce( (a,b) => a + ',' + b);
    ```

  > FireFox es el único navegador en el que `reduce()` tiene el mejor rendimiento.

- [image] **IE 11**

  [image: IE 11]
- [image] **Edge 16**

  [image: Edge 16]
- [image] **Safari 11** (MacOS X)

  [image: Safari 11]

  - En IE, Edge y Safari la concatenación manual también es muy lenta, por lo que no se recomienda excepto que se esté programando exclusivamente para Chrome.

#### Benchmark para arrays de muchos elementos

Ahora bien, cuando tratamos con más elementos en el array, el rendimiento se inclina en favor de los métodos nativos. Y además, la lógica previa a la función principal (si un método llama a otro, o si se verifica o no la cantidad o el tipo de los elementos, u otras optimizaciones) comienza a ser despreciable. Por ejemplo, tomando un benchmark para 1000 elementos ([JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/1000-x-join-vs-tostring-vs)), vemos como `join(',')`, `toString()` y `String()` comienzan a igualar la cantidad de operaciones por segundo. Esto es de esperarse, ya que el método tiene su mayor carga abocada a la concatenación, y es despreciable la lógica previa.

**Rendimiento según la cantidad de elementos del array**

[image: BENCHMARK POR CANTIDAD DE ELEMENTOS]

Este gráfico es de Chrome, pero los demás navegadores tienen exactamente el mismo comportamiento. La única excepción es la concatenación (`+= arr[i]`), que en el resto nunca supera a los métodos nativos. Acá se puede ver muy claro: cuando se incrementa el número de elementos, se iguala el rendimiento de los métodos nativos. La mayor carga del procesador está en la parte del proceso que va concatenando los elementos, y todo el resto del código pasa a ser irrelevante. **No hay diferencias significativas entre `join(',')`, `toString()` y `String()`**.

Ahora bien, seamos realistas. ¿Realmente nos importa el rendimiento de pocos elementos? Más aún en JavaScript, ¿estamos tan necesitados de ahorrarnos ~0.01µs? Creo que la respuesta es no.

Y para arrays de muchos elementos, los métodos nativos muestran un muy buen rendimiento, todos por igual. Pero llegado el caso (raro) de que estemos con un código en el que la concatenación sea el cuello de botella, existen otros métodos de optimización (Ropes, [Unrolling the loop](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desenroscado_de_bucles), etc.), que la mejor solución va a depender de cada caso en particular. En esos casos, recomiendo buscar bibliografía del tema.

---

## Buenas prácticas

No hay mucho que pueda decir sobre buenas prácticas. Los métodos son básicos, y cualquier desarrollador va a entender por igual a:

```
str1 = arr.join(',');

str2 = arr.toString();

str3 = String(arr);
```

Sólo puedo opinar que `arr.join(',')` es el más explícito de los 3, es análogo a lo que haríamos en otros lenguajes de programación, y si le pasamos `','` como parámetro no deja ningún lugar a dudas sobre qué estamos haciendo o cuál es el comportamiento. Lo prefiero porque creo que lo hace apenas más legible.

Comment: Me has sorprendido con esta impresionante respuesta tan bien trabajada. Esto merece una recompensa. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me alegro que te haya gustado... Me quedé jugando con los benchmarks desde [los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131078/convertir-un-array-en-string/131079#comment244327_131079) en la publicación que disparó tu pregunta... Es demasiado larga para una respuesta en el sitio, pero no me importa, me divertí investigando.